# How to set footer icons programatically in wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, icons, footer

I want to set footer icons programmatically in twenty seventeen theme in word press , i have created one page which is for add_menu_page and included it in function.php,i want that when link of any icon is defined then that icon is display in footer,can anyone help me to figure it out? i am including my custom page code here:

```
<?php 

function theme_options_panel(){
  add_menu_page('Theme page title', 'My Setting', 'manage_options', 'theme-options', 'wps_theme_func');
  add_submenu_page( 'theme-options', 'Settings page title', 'Demo menu', 'manage_options', 'theme-op-settings', 'wps_theme_func_settings');
  add_submenu_page( 'theme-options', 'FAQ page title', 'FAQ menu', 'manage_options', 'theme-op-faq', 'wps_theme_func_faq');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'theme_options_panel');

function wps_theme_func(){?>
        <form action="" id="frontpostform" method="post" style="margin: 7% 0% 0% 10%;" >
            <h1> Custom Footer icon Setting </h1> <br/>

            <label>Footer facebook Icon url: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="http://" required="required"> <br/><br/> 

            <label>Footer Twitter Icon url: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="http://" required="required"> <br/><br/>

            <label>Footer instagram Icon url: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="http://" required="required"> <br/><br/>

            <label>Footer google+ Icon url: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="http://" required="required"> <br/><br/>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-left: 10%">
    </form> 
<?php }


function wps_theme_func_settings(){
                echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="icon-options-general" class="icon32"><br></div>
                <h2>Demo text</h2></div>';
}


function wps_theme_func_faq(){
                echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="icon-options-general" class="icon32"><br></div>
                <h2>FAQ</h2></div>';
}
```

Comment: Why not use the customizer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now just save the data in wp_option table and retrive it in footer.

For save the data

```
add_action('init','saveCustomData');
function saveCustomData()
{
  if(!is_admin()){
    return;
  }
 if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
 {
    //change the name in your html 
    update_option('name',$_REQUEST['name'],true);
 }
}
```

Now to display in footer go to your footer.php adn write below code

```
echo get_option('name');
```

**Note : you need to do same thing for every html field. i have given the example only.**